# Is there any way to obtain real camera view from emülator in android 2.1 or 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, camera, android-camera

In my project I will get a picture from camera of phone but when I try to this with emulator, I can see only white-black square. Is there any way for real camera view and then to see picture that taken from camera to get in android emulator 2.1 or 2.2?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for real camera view and then to see picture that taken from camera to get in android emulator 2.1 or 2.2?

No, sorry. You will need to use an actual Android device to get an actual camera preview.